# Introductory phrases like "to tell the truth"

Tags: phrases, differences, conversation

What is the difference between the following introductory phrases?

> To tell the truth
>
> Frankly speaking
>
> To be honest

Are any of the phrases more old-fashioned or formal than the others or are they completely interchangeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, they all mean **in truth**:

> - actually,
> - really,
> - in fact,
> - in reality,
> - as a matter of fact,
> - in actual fact,
> - in point of fact,
> - if truth be told

The last four are bit a bit more formal.

Comment: I heard "in accordance with the principles of fairness and justice," once when someone was being facetious.

Comment: I tend to avoid the phrases "to tell the truth", "frankly speaking" and "to be honest" as they could suggest to your audience that you are not always open and honest.

Comment: Good list. All of them do NOT mean the same thing, though.

Answer (score 2):

They are all the same when used in a facetious way.

Each of them connotes a *different* thing when used appropriately. As in:

**To tell the truth,**:
You have misconstrued my words and started speaking at length on that basis. I could interrupt with 'To tell the truth, ...' to draw your attention to the fact that the truth is different from the presumption behind what you are currently saying.

...and so on.